# Why is the word ‘dictionary’ pronounced differently in British and American English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

Pronunciation of the word 'dictionary'
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/dictionary

from the page agove, in British pronunciation, the /n/ sound is not connected to the schwa sound that follows it. I would like to know if there are any links/posts that have a more specific overview of this phenomenon.

Comment: Because many words are pronounced differently in British and American English, just as many words are pronounced differently in British and Scots English. _Dictionary_ is just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the real difference between the British pronunciation and the U.S. pronunciation. The real difference is that in the British pronunciation, the vowel is a schwa /ə/, and in the American pronunciation, the vowel is an 'short e' /ɛ/.

In the British pronunciation, it may look like the /n/ sound is not connected to the schwa sound that follows it, but that is a consequence of the way the Cambridge dictionary uses raised schwas to represent an optional schwa sound. See their [pronunciation key](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/help/phonetics.html). The pronunciation of the /n/ is just as connected to the following vowel in British English as in American English.